# Azure Text Analytics & Python - Pull Values from Function

Tags: python, azure

This is a pretty basic question, I built a request using Azure's Text Analytics sentiment API and want to pull the overall positive, neutral, and negative numerical values.

The code is below:

```
def sentiment_analysis_example(client):

    documents = ["I wish you were here with me"]
    response = client.analyze_sentiment(documents=documents)[0]
    print("Document Sentiment: {}".format(response.sentiment))
    print("Overall scores: positive={0:.2f}; neutral={1:.2f}; negative={2:.2f} \n".format(
        response.confidence_scores.positive,
        response.confidence_scores.neutral,
        response.confidence_scores.negative,

    ))
          
sentiment_analysis_example(client)
```

```
Document Sentiment: neutral
Overall scores: positive=0.04; neutral=0.94; negative=0.02
```

Basically just want to pull the 0.04, 0.94, and 0.02 figures individually (i.e. return 0.04 when printing "positive").

I included as much of the code as I thought relevant but fully realize this might be hard to replicate as it requires the API. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean have an output like this?

```
positive=0.04
neutral=0.94
negative=0.02
```

Example:

```
def sentiment_analysis_example(client):

    documents = ["I wish you were here with me"]
    response = client.analyze_sentiment(documents=documents)[0]
    print("positive={0:.2f}".format(response.confidence_scores.positive))
    print("neutral={0:.2f}".format(response.confidence_scores.neutral))
    print("negative={0:.2f}".format(response.confidence_scores.negative))

sentiment_analysis_example(client)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, basically wanted to be able to pull the resulting numerical figures individually by assigning them as a variable. For example, if i were to enter "positive", 0.04 would the output

Comment: Okay. If just wanting to set variable, this should work: positive = response.confidence_scores.positive